# Simple Recursion

Tags: java, function, loops, recursion

I was playing around with this function:

```
public class x {

public static void main(String[] args) {
recurse(10);
}

public static int recurse(int theNumber) {

    if(theNumber == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println(theNumber);
        theNumber--;
        recurse(theNumber);
        System.out.println(theNumber);
    }

    return -1;
}
}
```

and I got this output:

10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Press any key to continue . . .

How is this possible? I understand where the countdown from 10 to 0 comes from.. but how on earth does it count back up?? I'm quite certain I'm missing a fundamental concept about recursion. Can someone fill in the blanks??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Habib explained it quite well actually. Just make sure you understand that the recursion is followed until the parameter theNumber is zero, hence the recursion terminates, and that this happens before any of the the last Sysout calls is done. Also keep in mind that the variable is not shared but local to each invocation. Visually, it might look like this

```
recurse(5)
print(5)
recurse(4)
  print(4)
  recurse(3)
    print(3)
    recurse(2)
      print(2)
      recurse(1)
         print(1)
         recurse(0)
         print(0)
      print(1)
    print(2)
  print(3)
print(4)
```

Calls that are in the same column belong to the same stackframe, i.e. same method invocation. Notice, how you decent in the call hierarchy before you actually reach the first print statement after the recursive invocation. This should make it clear, to you.

Comment: "Also keep in mind that the variable is not shared but local to each invocation." - this might be the kicker that i'm missing

Comment: Yeah, maybe. I know that this is kind of confusing in the beginning. One gets used to thinking in stack frames after a while :) It's like becoming a robot. Please upvote.

Answer (score 6):

That is because of the last `System.out.println(theNumber);` in your method. After recursively calling the method, and upcon completion of the method it is printing those values.

Comment: I understand that it is because of the last System.out.println(theNumber). I'm not understanding the flow. Is the recursive call completed, then the 2nd System.out.prinln(theNumber) call visited? I just don't understand the flow of this...

Comment: It never reaches the call until after it has converged. So in other words you will enter a call to recurse without printing anything. Then after the last recursive call the stack frames unwind.

Comment: Could you explain how the method executes in a step-by-step manner?

Comment: @user, I would suggest you to dry run the program with a smaller value , actually it is not call the last println statement untill the number reaches 0, then from that it executes rest of the method cals. But try it on paper first

Comment: I need a bit more elaboration if you could.

Comment: @user: Why don't you step thorough your program using a debugger? This would be much more enlightening than reading some comments.

Comment: @habib from what i see, and i'm clearly wrong, the method is called recursively down to 0, printing values along the way. then after all recursive calls are completed, it prints off the value of theNumber. from what i see, and again, i know i'm wrong, it should only print off the last remaining value of theNumber and then quit the method

Comment: @user, no, after reaching `0`, it returns to the call for example `recurse(1)`, then it prints `1`, then to previous call `recurse(2)` prints 2, and so on...

Answer (score 2):

For brevity, let's say you call `recurse(2)` in your main program. Then you have:

`theNumber` = 2 prints 2, decrements, calls `recurse(1)`

--> `theNumber` = 1, prints 1, decrements, calls `recurse(0)`

----> `theNumber` = 0, returns without printing

--> `theNumber` = 1 prints 0 (decremented from 1), returns

`theNumber` = 2 prints 1 (decremented from 2), returns

Comment: i understand everything up until theNumber=0, returns without printing. after that, shouldn't the function quit??

Comment: say method A looks like this:


`statement0;`


`statement1;`

`methodB();`

`statement3;`

In the general case, when `methodB` returns, execution will resume in `methodA` at `statement3`, even if `methodB` == `methodA` (i.e. you call the method that you are in). Try doing a search for what the call stack and a program counter are.

Comment: @user Why should it? Recursive methods are executed exactly like any other methods. Hence there is no "early quit".

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need-

```
public static int recurse(int theNumber) {

    System.out.println(theNumber);
    if (theNumber > 0) {
        theNumber--;
        recurse(theNumber);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last `System.out.println(theNumber)` is the reason of it. As you were asking about the Flow. First the recursive call is completed and then it's making BackTracking. Check this Link [BackTracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)

Answer (score 0):

As Habib said flow goes into recursion and then after completion of executing recursive function your last System.out.println(theNumber) gets called.

```
---->  public static int recurse(int theNumber) {
|   
|       if(theNumber == 0) {
|           return 0;
|       }
|   
|       else
|       {
|           System.out.println(theNumber);
|           theNumber--;
----------< recurse(theNumber);
            System.out.println(theNumber);
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

So the time when function returns from recursion theNumber contains the value which was was decremented by 1 only.

Comment: so does it go theNumber--, recurse(9), print, theNumber--, recurse(8), print, etc, etc. how on earth does it get to that last print statement on numerous occasions?

Comment: It goes like print, recurse(9) ; print, recurse(8) ; print, recurse(7).. and after returning from recurse(0) it prints(0) and returns. So print(0) ; print(1) upto first call where theNumber was passed with value 10

Answer (score 0):

Before your last syso statement you are calling recurse function so it is going on adding your calls on stack..and after reaching value to 0 it is returning to current function back by pulling values from stack.. and after that it is printing values by your last syso statement...